Air breathing ion thruster
Give me a clear Difference between Air breathing ion thruster which is used at VLEO
And the ion thrusters used above the LEO?

You might [edit] your question to explain the acronyms to educate the rest of us? (You've got some stray capitalisation in there too.)

A typical ion thruster uses a reservoir of gas usually inert gas that can be ionized (xenon, argon, etc) This design works even in a vacuum.

An air breathing ion engine uses a catchment to derive the gases to generate the thrust. Much like how a jet engine works. Thou the atmospheric density at altitude above 100 kilometers is near vacuum; it's inconsequential for air breathing combustion but there's still trace inert gases to use. This mitigates need to carry it's own propellant mass thus lightening the overall spacecraft but doesn't work in the interplanetary medium. Ideal for satellites since their service life is largely determined by their propellant quantity.

